# Трансформация кнопки при помощи анимации

Tags: css3, анимация

Может кто-нибудь показать на простом примере, как трансформировать кнопку призыва действия в круглую плавающую кнопку с перемещением из центра страницы в правый нижний угол?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы так сделал, плавно меняем `transform:position` и `border-radius`:

```css
body {
  margin:0
}

div.btn {
  user-select: none;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  animation: 
      transform-to-circle 2s forwards, 
      to-left-down-corner 2s forwards;
}

div.btn div{
  animation: 
      rotate-text-back 2s forwards;
}

div.btn:hover {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: lightgray;
  transition:200ms;
}
div.btn:active {
  background-color: gray;
}

@keyframes to-left-down-corner {
    from { 
      transform: translate(50vw,50vh) translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(0); 
    }
    to { 
      transform: translate(100vw,100vh) translate(-100%,-100%) rotate(90deg); 
    }
}

@keyframes rotate-text-back {
    from { 
      transform: rotate(0); 
    }
    to { 
      transform: rotate(-90deg); 
    }
}

@keyframes transform-to-circle {
    to { 
       border-radius: 50%;
       transform:rotate(90deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="btn"><div>hello</div></div>
```

**PS: В качестве бонуса вращаем квадрат и текст внутри него обратно**

Answer (score 4):

Как-то так можно поступить:

```css
.button {
    position: fixed;
    right: calc(50% - 40px);
    bottom: calc(50% - 40px);
    margin: auto;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-top: 12px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);
    transition: .3s;
    cursor: pointer;
    animation: transit 2s linear forwards;
    animation-delay: 2s;
}
.button:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    border-radius: 50%;
    animation: circle 1.5s linear infinite;
}
.button:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: red;
    background-color: white;
}
.button:hover:after {
    animation: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
}
@keyframes circle {
    100% {opacity: 0; transform: scale(1.5);}
}
@keyframes transit {
    100% {right: 10px; bottom: 10px;}
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
кнопка призыва действия 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно как-то так

```js
const button = document.getElementById('button')
button.onclick = function(e){
return e.target.classList[1] ? e.target.classList.remove("active") : e.target.classList.add("active");
}
```

```css
html,body {
height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
display: flex;
height: 100vh;
width: 100%;
background-color: #ffffff;
border: 1px solid red;
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}

.button {
  background-color: green;
  transition: all, 0.5s;
}

 .active {
  transform: translate(40vw, 40vh);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <div class='wrapper'>
    <button id='button' class='button'>BUTTON</button>
  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Приветствуем Вас на ru.stackoverflow